# How to generate simpler xml in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

if there any way to generate xml file in c# with form like this:

```
<data>
<tableName fieldname="value" fieldname2="value2" fieldname3="value3" />
</data>
```

I tried

```
System.Data.DataTable datatable = new System.Data.DataTable("tableName");
datatable.Columns.Add("filename", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("time", typeof(string));
datatable.Columns.Add("message", typeof(string));
.
.
datatable.WriteXml("Raports.xml")
```

and my xml has body like:

```
<tableName>
<filename>Raport_1201_1</filename>
<time>15:21:11.343</time>
<message>START</message>
</tableName>
```

Comment: Well I'd start off by using an XML API instead of `DataTable`. Have you tried using LINQ to XML? You want to create a root element, with a child element that has three attributes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, to use XAttributes inside Xelement:

```
XElement data = new XElement("data");
data.Add( new XElement("tableName",
new XAttribute("fieldname", "value"),
new XAttribute("fieldname", "value2"),
new XAttribute("fieldname", "value3")
)
);
data.save("some.xml");
```

Thanks for help everyone! ^^

Answer (score 0):

using [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7) from LINQ to XML API is probably the simplest way:

```
XElement data =
    new XElement("data",
        new XElement("tableName",
            new XElement("fieldname", "value"),
            new XElement("fieldname", "value2"),
            new XElement("fieldname", "value3")
        )
    );
```

Microsoft has great tutorial on [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml) or specifically [Creating XML Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/creating-xml-trees) with bunch of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument to create a new xml:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("data",
        new XElement("tableName",
            new XElement("filename", yourfilename),
            new XElement("time", yourTime),
            new XElement("message", yourMessage)
        )
    ));
doc.Save(yourFileName);
```